# Why is negative of a double number not working properly in C? (a = -a)

Tags: c, double, negative-number

I am writing a C code to filter out an ECG signal using a Highpass filter after lowpass filtering the original ECG signal in real time. I am using buffers(arrays) of type `double` for each stage of the filtering process. I am storing the results of each stage in .txt files.

After the highpass filtering, I want to multiply each array element by -1.

```
highpass[current] = 0.9405*lowpass[current];
        if (current >= 1) {
            highpass[current] = highpass[current] + 2.8773*highpass[current-1] - 2.8214*lowpass[current-1];
        }

        if (current >= 2) {
            highpass[current] = highpass[current] - 2.762*highpass[current-2] + 2.8214*lowpass[current-2];
        }
        if (current >= 3) {
            highpass[current] = highpass[current] + 0.8845*highpass[current-3] - 0.9405*lowpass[current-3];
        }


        highpass[current] = (-1)*(highpass[current]);

        fprintf(f_filt, "%f\n", highpass[current]);
```

This is the result **without** `highpass[current] = (-1)*(highpass[current]);` in the code.
This is the result of the values stored in `highpass` array.

> -1.335792
>   -8.407485
>   -26.681173
>   -58.894909
>   -104.809622
>   -163.116030
>   -231.988220
>   -308.388331
>   -387.765623
>   -465.136967
>   -536.568954
>   -599.441699
>   -651.411922
>   -689.653157
>   -711.520160,
>   -715.838577
>   -703.152983
>   -674.613971
>   -630.938055
>   -572.703877
>   -501.410514
>   -419.696250  ...

This is the result **with** `highpass[current] = (-1)*(highpass[current]);` in the code

> 1.335792
>   0.720535
>   7.796036
>   -17.457790
>   72.734919
>   -263.778646
>   975.351652
>   -3600.558972
>   13284.037019
>   -49033.608204
>   180956.075075
>   -667848.169960
>   2464767.673364
>   -9096531.912036
>   33571847.465338
>   -123900987.630354
>   457271635.575387
>   -1687616504.720729
>   6228353648.871813
>   -22986495502.953163
>   84834453086.781082
>   -313091851247.447750
>   1155503498293.337600
>   -4264525982539.895000,
>   15738751014276.246000
>   -58085771901392.500000
>   214372595024865.500000
>   -791168094928817.120000
>   2919901932244147.000000
>   -10776252668138970.000000
>   39771069118859136.000000
>   -146779960304163170.000000  ....

Why is the negation not happening when i run `highpass[current] = (-1)*(highpass[current]);`?

Comment: What do you expect?  The first value is indeed negated and the others are changed, which is not surprising considering that they are computed using the previous one.

Comment: Store the result after negating into a different variable. Because currently you are manipulating your result, this is effecting rest of the values.

Comment: `highpass[current]` depends on values of `highpass[current-1]`, `highpass[current-2]`, and `highpass[current-3]`.   All of which will have been multiplied by `-1` - and that will affect the calculations before `highpass[current]` is multiplied by `-1`.

Comment: and you shouldn't use `highpass[current] = (-1)*(highpass[current]);`. Just `highpass[current] = -highpass[current];` is enough, shorter and more readable

Comment: This is only a part of the code. So, every time i compute a new value for `highpass` the `current` variable is incremented and the above piece of code is run. The above piece of code produces only one value of `highpass`. For example, for the first valid value produced by highpass, the above piece of code is run once. After this `current` variable is incremented and and a new value for highpass is computed.

Comment: The rest of the code is very long hence i cannot add it here. The only  problem is that the negation of the computed value is not happening as expected. The data type of highpass is double.